# Is it possible to have multiple socket-io connections from a single client without loosing previous socket

Tags: javascript, sockets, socket.io, flask-socketio

I've been learning flask-socketio. The aim is to make a p2p-like (should not be correctly saying) chat app using socket-io which works in a LAN. All the users have static IP address which everyone knows. There are 4 devices in LAN. Each going to install the flask-app in their own system. This is the app.py and chat.html(client in JS)

This is the `app.py`

```
from flask import Flask,render_template,request,url_for,redirect
from flask_socketio import SocketIO,join_room

app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app,cors_allowed_origins="*")
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'mysecret'

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/chat')
def chat():
    username = request.args.get('username')
    room    = request.args.get('room')

    if username and room:
        return render_template('chat.html',username=username,room=room)
    else:
        return redirect(url_for('home'))
        
@socketio.on('join_room')
def joinchannel(data):
    app.logger.info("{} is ONLINE NOW!".format(data['username']))
    join_room(data['room'])
    socketio.emit('join_room_announce',data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=5000,debug=True)
```

and the `templates/chat.html`

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>START CHAT</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>lets start the chat room {{ room }}</h1>
<div id="messages"></div>

<form>
    
    <input type="text" placeholder="enter message">
    <button type="submit">send</button>
</form> 
</body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.3.0/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
    const socket = io.connect("http://192.168.1.2:5000");
    socket.on('connect',function() {
        socket.emit('join_room',{
        username: "{{ username }}",
        room: "{{ room }}"
    })
});
    socket.on('join_room_announce', function (data) {
        alert(data.username);
    })
</script>
</html>
```

This is straight. Alice is running app.py in her system and trying to connect to Bob (192.168.1.2:5000). As Bob is runnning app.py in his system and inside LAN, Alice got connected.
Bob as able to see "Alice" as a popup in his browser after Alice joined same room as Bob.

This is good. But what if Alice also want to connect with Frank (192.168.1.3:5000)? How can Alice modify her socketio connection in client side, server side to make it possible. I have tried adding another `io.connect` in chat.html. Therefore 2 `io.connect` function and only the first `io.connect()` is working.

If the straight answer is " this is not possible with socketio", is there some tweak to make it possible? Eventually Alice could connect to Bob, Frank or many and other members can also have same. Basically, one person should be able to connect with more than one person.

This may be possible with WebRTC-like protocols. But, this is not we want here. I hope there is some tweak to make this possible with socket-io.
Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, you can. you just have to put them in different variables.

```
const socketConnectionOne = io.connect("http://192.168.1.2:5000");

socketConnectionOne.on('connect',function() {
        socket.emit('join_room',{
        username: "{{ username }}",
        room: "{{ room }}"
    })
});

socketConnectionOne.on('join_room_announce', function (data) {
        alert(data.username);
    })

const socketConnectionTwo = io.connect("http://192.168.1.2:5000");

socketConnectionTwo.on('connect',function() {
        socket.emit('join_room',{
        username: "{{ username }}",
        room: "{{ room }}"
    })
});

socketConnectionTwo.on('join_room_announce', function (data) {
        alert(data.username);
    })
```

Comment: Is there any changes needed in app.py? (flask-SocketIO)

Comment: Also, what if we want to scale up. That means we have to deal with more clients. At that point, code would get large.

Comment: you don't have to change anything in the app.py. because it will create a new instance on a new connection.

Comment: and what scenario would you want multiple socket connections from one client?

Comment: The flask app has a dictonary of all userid and IP addresses of members in LAN. Say if there are 10 members in LAN and Alice want to chat with, say 5 members. Alice searches their username and gets the ip address from the dictionary. Therefore, Alice would need multiple socket connections without loosing previous chat. Alice searches for user James, looks in python dictionary, gets ip address, connect to that server using js client we have (chat.html).

Comment: Or i would ask in this way. Is it possible to send the IP to connect with from backend to chat.html of Alice without Alice refreshing the page(chat.html) ? Alice searches a username, backend checks in a python dictionary backend gives it to chat.html, now connect to that ip with ```io.connect()``` dynamically without refreshing the page

Comment: I think you are missing the purpose of socket. you only run app.py once but the client page chat.html will be loaded by multiple participants. after that, there will be no direct connections between the clients. if you want to send a message to one client you have to emit event to the server and the server will send it to the other client.